# Unix: command to strip white space characters

Tags: unix, whitespace, pwd, pbcopy

When I do the following unix command:

```
pwd | pbcopy
```

is there something I can add to the command so that the string copied to my clipboard does not have any trailing whitespace?

(fyi: The reason I ask is because when I pipe the output to pbcopy, it copies a newline character at the end, which for my purposes, I don't want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that effect with:

```
echo -n `pwd` | pbcopy
```

Comment: That didn't work. It copied the string 'pwd' instead of the output of pwd.

Comment: Note these are backticks, not single quotes.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I thought they were single quotes. Perfect, that worked great. Thanks!